# How to get person's address using Facebook Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am able to get the name and email like this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response)
{
  alert ("Name when logged in:" + response.name);
  alert ("Name when logged in:" + response.email);
});
```

But in the FB documentation, I don't see how to get address.  Also, how can I download their photo?

As I understand it, their photo can be retrieved from this url: http://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/picture

But how do I get their facebook user id?

Also, to get the address, I am trying something like this:

```
          alert ("Location:" + response.location);
          alert ("Location:" + response.location.city);
          alert ("Location:" + response.location.country);
          alert ("Location:" + response.location.zip);
          alert ("Location:" + response.location.state);
```

But that doesn't work.  Anyone know how to get at these fields?
Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that sounds very creepy.

Comment: @Joseph its very common.  The user gives permissions to do this first.

Comment: If this is to create one of those annoying 'See your top firends' type app then I vote no one helps him :P

Comment: @Genadinik I see.  Perfectly valid I suppose... but now I know why I never got into FB :P

Comment: @Joseph if you think about it, it is the same info as you would give when creating an account on many other sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FB.api('/me')` Will give you the user's id without requiring any special permissions.

You can't get address as such, you can get `location` using the `user_location` permission. Then you'll be able to get it via the same `/me` method.

Facebook Developers doc:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: I already get the user to allow getting the location. But this seems to be breaking the page: response.user_location - how do I correctly pull this info from the API? Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully you already figured it out, the permission is 'user_location', which you ask for when authorising, the property itself is 'location'. Try console.log(response) to see what available.

Answer (score 3):

Actually all that info is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

But it took a long time to find that page!